# Смена GET-параметра при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: php, get

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку передавался `GET`-параметр, например `?id=1`. При повторном нажатии на ссылку этот `GET`-параметр менялся, например на 2. Тоесть, нажал на ссылку - ?`id=1`, еще раз нажал - `?id=2`, опять нажал `?id=1` и так далее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ( isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id]==1) 
         echo "<a href='/?id=2'>ссылка</a>";
        else
         echo "<a href='/?id=1'>ссылка</a>";
```

Comment: Боже, как же это просто, а я пытался подставлять переменную и менять её, и с помощью сессий пытался, а тут, оказывается, просто ссылку с разными параметрами нужно вывести. Спасибо!